# Why does the 'Added to cart' message still come up?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have coded a custom 'Added to cart' message for WooCommerce and after that I used the conditional tag 'is_cart()' to disable the message on the cart page but it still shows up.

How can I disable the message being shown on cart page?

Here is my code example:

```
function iw_add_to_cart_message_function( $message, $product_id ) {

    if (!is_cart()) {

        $message    = sprintf(esc_html__('%s has been added by to your cart pompidompidom.','iwebbers'), get_the_title( $product_id ) );

        return $message;

    }
}

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'iw_add_to_cart_message_function', 10, 2 );
```

I just tried the following IF STATEMENT and it works:

```
global $woocommerce;
if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='no') {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `wc_add_to_cart_message`

it Return message rather than add it.

go refer link: [docs.woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_to_cart_message.html)